# Regex: Using capture data further in the regex

Tags: php, regex

I want to parse some text that start with `":"` and could be surround with parentheses to stop the match so:

`"abcd:(someText)efgh"` and

```
"abcd:someText"
```

will return `someText`.

but i have a problem to set the parentheses optionnal.

I make this but it does not works:

```
$reg = '#:([\\(]){0,1}([a-z]+)$1#i';

$v = 'abc:(someText)def';

var_dump(preg_match($reg,$v,$matches));

var_dump($matches);
```

The `$1` makes it failed.

i don't know how to tell him :

> If there is a "(" at the beginning, there must be ")" at the end.

Comment: can some text contain numbers? like `0`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex will match either :word or :(word) groups 1 and 2 hold the respective results.

```
if (preg_match('/:([a-z]+)|\(([a-z]+)\)/i', $subject, $regs)) {
$result = ($regs[1])?$regs[1]:$regs[2];
} else {
$result = "";
}
```

Comment: maybe: $result = ($regs[1])?$regs[1]:$regs[2]; ?

Comment: @Leto I have no idea about php :) so you will have to figure that part yourself :) Editing now.

Comment: @FailedDev: You might be interested [in this variant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7698977/regex-using-capture-data-further-in-the-regex/7699202#7699202) ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can't test if the count of something is equal to another count. It's a regex problem who can only be used with regular language (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language). To achieve your goal, as you asked - and that is if there's a '(' should be a ')' -, you'll need a Context-Free Language (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_language).

Anyway, you can use this regex:

```
'/:(\([a-z]+\)|[a-z]+)/i
```

Comment: I'm not "counting" the "(". If the first "(" is set then $1 contains it and if the first "(" is not set then $1 will contains nothing. That's the way i see that.

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa : Results of your regex : 

abcd
:(someText)efgh
abcd
someText

Comment: PCRE is not regular only any longer.

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa I did not think to use pipe (|), sounds good but why do you use .* ?

Comment: As you can see also the other answer has the pipe. It is more clear to use the regex using the pipe.

Answer (score 1):

To return the match of different sub-patterns in the regex to the same element of the `$matches` array, you can use [*named subpattern*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.subpatterns.php) with the [internal option `J`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) to allow duplicate names. The return element in `$matches` is the same as the name of the pattern:

```
$pattern = '~(?J:.+:\((?<text>[^)]+)\).*|.+:(?<text>.+))~';

$texts = array(
    'abc:(someText)def',
    'abc:someText'
);

foreach($texts as $text) 
{
    preg_match($pattern, $text, $matches);
    echo $text, ' -> ', $matches['text'], '<br>';
}
```

Result:

```
abc:(someText)def -> someText
abc:someText -> someText
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Fyjcj1)

Comment: @FailedDev: I have put the links to the PHP Manual in there, both pages contain that info, you need to scroll down a bit on each of them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.+:\((.+)\).*|.+:(.+)
```

if $1 is empty there are no parentheses and $2 has your text.

Answer (score 0):

regex: with look-behind

```
"(?<=:\(|:)[^()]+"
```

test with grep:

```
kent$  echo "abcd:(someText)efgh
dquote> abcd:someOtherText"|grep -Po "(?<=:\(|:)[^()]+"

someText
someOtherText
```